# Python - Changing IDLE Text color not working on Windows

Tags: python, python-idle, colorama

I am using [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) to try to simulate in the `IDLE` shell. Here is my code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

My output looks something like this:

[image: Error]

What is incorrect? Why does it print those wierd letters in the start? I am using `Windows OS`.

**P.S: I've also tried running this in Command Prompt, and I got a similar output**

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've also tried running this in `Command Prompt` and got nigh-on the same output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a [call to `init`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) (scroll down to "Usage"):

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init

# Here
init()

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Which outputs, colored

```
some red text
and with a green background
and in dim text

back to normal now
```

This still doesn't work in IDLE, but works in `cmd` and `powershell`.

Comment: Is there some way to do it in IDLE? (*Just curious*)

Comment: @Xilpex Honestly, couldn't tell you. I don't write Python or use IDLE regularly. I just figured this out from reading the docs. You could try other text libraries though. Python surely has a "curses" port, and curses has been great every time I've used it. It does its best to deal with shortcomings of the console being used.

Comment: @Xilpex https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html Looks like Curses might ship with Python?

Comment: @Xilpex Colorama is not supported in IDLE

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Colorama assumes that output goes to the Windows text console.  The Command Prompt uses that console.  So does python.exe when started from an icon or Start menu entry.  Colorama sends ANSI escape codes and also makes win32 calls understood by the console.  It does not work directly work with graphics frameworks whose text widgets have text colored by an different method.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using python idle colorama just does not work, other ide's like replit, vscode etc... can use colorama with no problem, and according to 'Carcigenicate' using the init() allows cmd and powershell to use colorama correctly.